# similar text in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, similarity

I've PHP array something like this

```
$array = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world", "fooo", "bar1", "hall_o", "wor1ld", "foo", "bard", "hzallo", "w44orld");
```

I want to compare each element of an array with remaining elements.

Ex: I want to compre `"foo" with "bar", "hallo", "world", "fooo", "bar1", "hall_o", "wor1ld", "foo", "bard", "hzallo" and "w44orld"`.

Then, I want to compre `"bar" with "foo", "hallo", "world", "fooo", "bar1", "hall_o", "wor1ld", "foo", "bard", "hzallo", "w44orld"`
and so on till last element.

Let's consider element, which we are comparing as `$var_1` and variable for remaining elements as $var_2; 
If `similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent);` returns `$percent value > 90%` then I want to print 
`$var_1` and all corresponding similar text values of `$var_2` for which matching percentage > 90

Currently I'm planning to use two loops to achieve this, external loop for `$var_1` and internal loop for `$var_2` . 
Each element of the `array` can have value upto 5000 characters and there can be 1000 elements in a array, so my current logic is very expensive.

Any direction to handle it in better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the indexing to work, the array `$arr` must have unique values:

```
$arr = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world", "fooo", "bar1", "hall_o", "wor1ld", "bard", "hzallo", "w44orld");
$dexed = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $dexed[$key]['val'] = $value;
    $dexed[$key]['key'] = $key;
}
$out = array();//output
$rev = array();//reverse lookup array
$t = 80;//threshold value
$cnt = count($dexed);
$k = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<$cnt-1; $i++){
    for ($j=$i+1; $j<$cnt; $j++){
        //similar_text calculates differently depending on order of arguments
        similar_text($dexed[$i]['val'], $dexed[$j]['val'], $percent1);
        similar_text($dexed[$j]['val'], $dexed[$i]['val'], $percent2);
        if (($percent1 >= $t) || ($percent2 >= $t)){
            //check if value already exists under different key
            if (in_array($dexed[$i]['val'], array_keys($rev))){
                if ( ! in_array($dexed[$j]['val'], array_keys($rev))){
                    $fkey = $rev[$dexed[$i]['val']];//key found
                    $next = count($out[$fkey]);
                    $out[$fkey][$next]['val'] = $dexed[$j]['val'];
                    $out[$fkey][$next]['key'] = $dexed[$j]['key'];
                    $rev[$dexed[$j]['val']] = $fkey;
                }
            } else {
                $out[$k][0]['val'] = $dexed[$i]['val'];
                $out[$k][0]['key'] = $dexed[$i]['key'];
                $out[$k][1]['val'] = $dexed[$j]['val'];
                $out[$k][1]['key'] = $dexed[$j]['key'];
                $rev[$dexed[$i]['val']] = $k;
                $rev[$dexed[$j]['val']] = $k;
                $k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once `$out` is generated, use the following to generate an index array:

```
$index = array();
foreach ($out as $key => $group){
    $cnt = count($group);
    foreach ($group as $key2 => $word){
        for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++){
            if ($i != $key2){
                $index[$word['key']][] = $key.':'.$i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Access all similar words for a given key (the key value for the word in the original array `$arr`);

```
$key = 2;
foreach ($index[$key] as $value){
    $parts = explode(':', $value);
    echo '<p>'.$out[$parts[0]][$parts[1]]['val'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: You are genius. This is working perfectly one dimensional array. I'm still trying to understand how it's working perfectly. If input array $arr is array(
    key1  => value1,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
) Then how can we print key & value in $out ?

Comment: I've "question id" and "question" stored in MySQL Database. I'm fetching "question id" and "questions" in PHP and then applying logic mentioned to get duplicate questions. Now after identification of duplicate questions, I want to find out respective "Question Id".

Comment: @pawanmude - I changed my answer to maintain index values.

Comment: Simply Superb Solution. Thank You Sir once again. I managed to get required "Question ID" for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you're proposing is slow if the list gets bigger than trivial and won't work very well.  Here's something that might, and will also be algorithmically efficient.

First, create an inverted index of letter bigrams (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram).  For example (assuming case insensitivity):

1. "foo" => ^f,fo,oo,o$
2. "hzallo" => ^h,hz,za,al,ll,o$

You can use an underscore instead of ^ and $, which are pseudocharacters.  I think they'll help you rank the results.

Now to find similar words you can use a typical ranking algorithm (see tf*idf and simpler token-count-based algorithms) to rank the best matches.  So, given "hallo,"

QUERY(^h,ha,al,ll,lo,o$) AGAINST index_of_words

& you'll get a good match for "hzallo" because ^h,al,ll,lo,o$ all match.

You'll need something like Solr or your database's TEXT index to do this unless you want to write a simple inverted index, but it's worth it.  The lookup will be orders of magnitude faster than what you're entertaining, and the results will be ranked by closeness.

Afterwards, you can use something like levenshtein, but I don't think you'll need to in many cases.

Comment: Thank you Jaimie for proposing new logic. Currently I'm using solution provided by "Pé de Leão" is working perfectly and giving desired output in around 2.5 mins.

Comment: 2.5 mins is rather slow.  Trust me, you want to use an inverted index with some sort of fuzziness unless I'm misunderstanding.  At its core, that's still how Google even works.